# Extract Java comment body (without //, /*, */)

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I use the eclipse java jdt parser, which seems to be missing the following feature: extracting comment bodies.

The following code:

```
class CommentBodyExtractor extends ASTVisitor {
  @Override public boolean visit(BlockComment node) {
    final int start = node.getStartPosition();
    final int end = start + node.getLength();
    final String comment = source.substring(start, end);
    System.out.println(comment);
    return false;
  }
}
```

when run on the following code:

```
/* 
* comment_body
*/
```

returns the complete comment code, while what I am looking for is code that will return just `comment_body`.

I could do simple string manipulation like remove `/*` from the beginning of the string and `*/` from the end and `*` from line beginnings. However I would like to use a more elegant way (some library?), do you know any?

Comment: Maybe [QDox](https://github.com/paul-hammant/qdox) can help?

Comment: Thanks @LanceJava I have not used this library before, I will it a try.

Comment: Unless there is a convention that *everybody* uses on comment content, you won't find a good way to extract your comment_body.  Anybody could place any text in the "left margin" of a multiline comment; how will you know what is comment text, and what is just boilerplate?    You can make assumptions about this; expect them to break in real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parser needs well-defined rules in order to process input text. JLS does not define any structure for the text between `/*` and `*/`, hence a parser cannot do much.

If you want to programmatically operate on comments, you should probably use javadoc comments, from which the JDT parser creates a structured `Javadoc` element, that reflects the semantic content rather than the raw text.